# Is something configured to be in Spanish‽

Tags: bug, status-deferred, user-interface, moderation

I just spotted this message in my inbox:

[image: Message inbox with one message partially in Spanish]

Google Translate says the Spanish sentence means "Get more information in the help center.".

Comment: Well, that's not good... We've previously had several reports of incorrect Russian localisation, but Spanish is new (to me at least).

Comment: For reference: Russian language reports on Meta Stack Exchange [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376522/1099857), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378773/1099857), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386556/1099857); and Meta Stack Overflow [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422735/15497888), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423675/15497888)

Comment: It's the russian hackers again!

Comment: Looks like this is probably related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376522/997587) flagged it internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll put my bets on this being an instance / variation of this bug posted on MSE (current [status-review](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-review)): [Wrong language in recent achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376522/997587).

(search query: `is:q russian language [bug]` (there have been several bugs reported with russian in particular))